# MSBuild Defintion - Suppress Warning Messages for Specific Solutions

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, build-process, build-definition

Within the MSBuild Build Definitions, I'm trying to suppress all warning messages output for specific C# and vb.net solutions. I want the warnings to return 0 for a particular solution. I've been reading that you can fix this using NoWarn within MSBuild Arguments but i can't find the syntax for an entire solution

$/Etc/Etc1/Etc2/Etc3/Etc4/Solution.sln - 0 error(s), **500 warning(s)**

MSBuild Arguments: /p:NoWarn"Solution.sln"

**There are multiple solutions within the Build but I only want to target only specific solutions

Answer (score 1):

To suppress all warning messages for a specific solution, you need to use **/property:WarningLevel=0** MSBuild argument. Open build definition, go to Process -> 2.Build -> 5.Advanced -> MSBuild argument.

[image]

Comment: That's very close to what I need. What if there are multiple solutions within a Build and i want to target only specific solutions to surpress

Comment: @CowboyCoder, seems no easy way to use this argument for one specific solution. The method described in my above reply will suppress warnings for all solutions. For your scenario, maybe you need to create one more build definition specially for that solution you want to suppress warning messages.