# Is there a program to help manage error suppression in TFS?

Tags: tfs, code-analysis, suppress, suppression

I recently inherited a large solution containing a lot of suppressed messages in its code base.

Waiting to simply run across each of these messages one by one as I happen to touch parts of the code is a terrible way of handling all of these suppressed analysis errors.

While there is a small amount of suppressions that are considered valid (such as in auto-generated code files) most are needing to be fixed.

Is there some sort of plug-in or process through TFS that anyone can recommend as far as managing these code analysis issues in an efficient manner?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, Version 14.0.2107.0 D14REL

Comment: Unfortunately, there's nothing out of the box in that case.  However, there are a few approaches you could potentially take.  It would be easier to suggest something if you could elaborate a bit with regards to what you mean by "managing" the suppressions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the /property:WarningLevel=0 MSBuild argument to suppress all build warnings. Open build definition, go to Process -> 2.Build -> 5.Advanced -> MSBuild argument. Check my reply in this link: [MSBuild Defintion - Suppress Warning Messages for Specific Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571416/msbuild-defintion-suppress-warning-messages-for-specific-solutions)